# can't access http://localhost:28017 when enable auth for mongod

Tags: mongodb, http, console

I can't access http://localhost:28017 when enabled auth for `mongod`; it always pops up username/password even if I fill in correct username/password. I have enabled HTTP & REST in the initial parameter file.

The YAML format parameter file which I use:

```
net:
port: 27017
http:
 enabled: true
 RESTInterfaceEnabled: true
 security:
 authorization: enabled
```

But when I disable `mongod` authorization, I can login at http://localhost:28017 successfully with no need to fill in username/password.

What's the reason? Does it not support HTTP console under the authorization for 3.0? My version is 3.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

First let me add the standard caveat - do not use the built in HTTP/REST interface in production, only for testing, it should be disabled on production systems.

On to the issue: MongoDB 3.0 now [defaults](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#scram-sha-1-and-existing-user-credentials) to using SCRAM-SHA-1 for challenge response (username and password) based logins and I am assuming you created your users from scratch in 3.0 (if they were imported from 2.6 they would work unless you did a schema upgrade).  The reason you are failing is that the HTTP/REST interface [does not support](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-status-interface-security) using the new credential mechanism in 3.0 to log in, you have to use the old mechanism.

Basically, you need to have a user with the legacy [MONGODB-CR](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#mongodb-cr-authentication) credentials if you want to use the REST interface authenticated.  Create the user you wish to use, then use the [changeUserPassword](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.changeUserPassword/) command to switch to the MONGODB-CR mechanism.  Something like the following:

```
db.changeUserPassword("restuser", "SOh3TbYhx8ypJPxm", "MONGODB-CR")
```

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use "MongoDB compass commiunity", download it from mongodb website, it is like phpmyadmin for mysql